# Is it possible to reverse Diffie-Hellman key exchange?

Tags: diffie-hellman

Is it possible to reverse Diffie-Hellman key exchange to get the private key of one of the parties, given a large prime number 'p' .

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly possible given enough compute resources.

However, if you mean to ask whether it is computationally feasible for an eavesdropper to derive the private keys, then- *no, it is not*.

Refer to the [secrecy chart on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation):

The private keys `a` and `b` are meant to be known only to Alice and Bob respectively.

In the real world, the [Logjam attack](https://weakdh.org/) is one example of how adversaries with nation state-level compute resources (such as the NSA) could theoretically break Diffie Hellman implementations, relying on the fact that a small set of primes were used across most common implementations.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to reverse Diffie-Hellman key exchange to get the
>   private key of one of the parties, given a large prime number $p$ .

As this is formulated: **yes**.

Using a large prime is *not* sufficient for a secure Diffie-Hellman key exchange.
For DH to be secure you want the *Computational Diffie-Hellman Problem* (CDH) to be hard which in turn implies that you want the *Discrete Logarithm Problem* (DLOG) to be hard as well. Solving the DLOG means recovering either partie's private key, solving the CDH means recovering the resulting shared secret.

Now we can construct large primes $p$ (like 2048-bit and longer) for which the DLOG is easy. For example if we chose an $n$-bit prime $p$ such that $p-1$ has only prime factors smaller than $B$ (namely $k$ many) we can compute discrete logarithms in time less than $\mathcal O(k(\log n+\sqrt B))$ using the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm).

---

However, the following statement holds:

> It is computationally not feasible using classical computers to solve the CDH problem if the
>   sampling of the private exponents has sufficient entropy and the field
>   prime $p$ is a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_prime) of sufficient size and the common generator $g$ has [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) $>2$.

Where sufficiently large means 2048-bit long or more for the prime and 128-bit or more entropy for each exponent.

And yes, good real-world implementations do look out for these things and are thus secure (from a theoretical point of view).